# error: variable-sized object may not be initialized| (C language)

Tags: c, variables

I am a beginner of programming so I am not familiar to errors yet.

```
int integer=1;
struct myStruct **str1[integer] = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *));
```

I have this code segment, and I get following error:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized|
```

I figured out the problem is causing from the variable 'integer' as when I delete it, I don't face this error. But I can't understand why I am seeing it because I already initialized 'integer' variable. Also, I already initialized "myStruct" structure and initializing str1 right here.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Are you using Visual Studio ?

Comment: I was writing in CodeBlocks editor when I faced this one

Comment: @haccks: MSVS doesn't permit variable-length arrays at all, so it wouldn't produce that message.

Comment: Your variable `str1` is an array, not a pointer, so you can't initialize it with the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Specifically, `str1` is an array of `integer` elements, each of which is a `struct myStruct**`, i.e., a pointer to pointer to `struct myStruct`. (And please don't name an `int` variable `integer`; it's confusing.

Comment: @KeithThompson; I know MSVC does't support C99 that's why I asked. (I did't understand the error at that time).

Comment: The initializer `{ ... }` could be wrapped around the call to `malloc()` if the code is initializing an automatic array. But it is not clear what benefit there is to have an array of size 1, so that you'll always need to reference `str1[0]` (or `*str1`) to get at the data it holds.

Comment: Thanks you all for interesting :)

Comment: @user3108849; Now you have [previlege to upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can upvote any answer you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that because `integer` is not a compile-time integer constant (and it won't be even if you define it as `const int integer = 1;`), the array you declare using it is a VLA — variable length array.  And you cannot define initializers for VLAs, even when you know the size at compile time.

The C standard says:

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.9 Initialization
>
> ¶3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
>   object type that is not a variable length array type.

That's a constraint; there is no wriggle room.  Though shalt not initialize a VLA.

---

#### Further scrutiny

In this context, I'd probably use `1` (or even nothing) as the array dimension:

```
int integer=1;
struct myStruct **str1[1] = { malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *)) };
```

Or:

```
int integer=1;
struct myStruct **str1[] = { malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct *)) };
```

Note the use of initializer `{ ... }` braces which are necessary for initializing an array.

However, it is not remotely clear what you are trying to do here; you have 3 levels of pointer on the LHS and only 1 in the `sizeof` on the RHS.  While `sizeof(struct myStruct *) == sizeof(struct myStruct **)`, it is not clear what you are up to.  My suspicion is you really want:

```
size_t str_size = 1;
struct myStruct **str1 = malloc(sizeof(*str_size) * str_size);
```

This allocates space for one `struct myStruct` pointer, but the allocation can grow later so that you can have many such pointers in an array, the size of which is described by the `str_size` variable.

This is not initializing an array (or structure), so the `{ ... }` must be absent.

I'll also note that I've kept the `str` prefix out of deference to your code, but most people expect `str` to refer to 'string', not 'structure' (think `strlen()` etc).  So you should probably not use `str` as the prefix.  (And, in my view, adult programmers do not use 'my' as a prefix either. However, not everyone agrees with me — witness 'MySQL' and 'My Documents', though in the latter case, one might argue that we're being treated as children anyway.)

Comment: I often used the name like `My_func`, `My_procd`, `My_cursor` in SQL but I will not use from today.

Comment: Just as well I never had to review your code. Unless the MY was for Malaysia or you somehow managed to come up with an abbreviation (my = 'managed yaks') that warranted it, then I'd have sent you back to fix the code with a more meaningful prefix (such as your initials).